# Visual Studio gives partial code coverage for new initializers

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage

I'm using `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3`.

I am failing to get 100% code coverage on this simple `Unit Test`:

```
TEST_METHOD(New)
{
    int* test = new int(4); //shows the line as partially covered
    int* test2 = new int;   //shows line as 100% covered
}
```

This happens if the statements are in the code called by the test function as well.

The only setting changed from the default for the project is the `/profile` switch, which is necessary to get any code coverage to work in the first place.

I noticed that `new` when used without an `initializer` shows `100%` coverage, but for classes I usually initialize them right away and I would like to find a way to do it without reducing the code coverage.

Code Disassembly

```
                int* test = new int(4); //shows the line as partially covered
0F951D53  push        4  
0F951D55  call        operator new (0F9512B2h)  
0F951D5A  add         esp,4  
0F951D5D  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0ECh],eax  
0F951D63  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-0ECh],0  
0F951D6A  je          UnitTest1::UnitTest1::New+56h (0F951D86h)  
0F951D6C  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0ECh]  
0F951D72  mov         dword ptr [eax],4  
0F951D78  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0ECh]  
0F951D7E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-100h],ecx  
0F951D84  jmp         UnitTest1::UnitTest1::New+60h (0F951D90h)  
0F951D86  mov         dword ptr [ebp-100h],0  
0F951D90  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-100h]  
0F951D96  mov         dword ptr [test],edx  
            int* test2 = new int;   //shows line as 100% covered
0F951D99  push        4  
0F951D9B  call        operator new (0F9512B2h)  
0F951DA0  add         esp,4  
0F951DA3  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0F8h],eax  
0F951DA9  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0F8h]  
0F951DAF  mov         dword ptr [test2],eax
```

Looking at the code, I'm guessing the `jmp` statements cause the code coverage analysis tool to see some statements as not hit.

Comment: Ignore previous comments.  I had confused "new with initializer", and "array new"!

Comment: Try looking at the assembly and see if there are any unexpected jumps or something.

Comment: @MartinBonner I just added it, I suspect one of the two jumps might be the cause, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have an option which means that `new` always behaves as `new(nothrow)` (in other words, `new` returns `nullptr` if the allocation fails).

The assembly is checking if `operator new` has returned nullptr (and if so, not storing 4 at the returned address).  You need to test the case where the allocation failed in order to have complete coverage.  In C++, the assembly looks like:

```
    int * test;
    int * tmp = operator new(sizeof(int));
    if (tmp != nullptr) {
        *tmp = 4;
        test = tmp;
    } else {
        test = nullptr;
    }
```

**Edit**

Ah ha!  In [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/08/06/new-in-vs-2015-zcthrowingnew/) Microsoft explain that the generated code for new has been testing for a null return, *just in case you link in the `nothrow` version*.  With VC2015, they have provided an option to say "don't bother doing that, `new` will throw, it will never return `nullptr`.

So, to avoid the unnecessary branch, add:  `/Zc:throwingNew` to the compilation options.  (This will also help performance generally.)

Comment: So there's no concise way of making it mark it as fully covered? I'm already testing the case where `nullptr` is sent to the functions I'm using anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I've searched the Microsoft website but couldn't find this, your Google-fu is on a different level. Accepted your answer.